# Centos java custom service

Tags: java, service, centos

I have a script.sh that set some environment variable and start a java server.

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME="/opt/java"
export ....

nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java "$MEMORY_JAVA_OPS" -classpath "$MY_CLASSPATH" $MAIN_CLASS  &
```

I would like to transform this script (now is launched by /etc/rc.d/rc.local) in a service.

I tried many examples found online and over StackOverflow.
I created myservice.service file using many templates found online... No one work!

one example is:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyService Java Process Restart Upstart Script
After=auditd.service systemd-user-sessions.service time-sync.target

[Service]
User=root
TimeoutStartSec=0
Type=simple
KillMode=process
#export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk-9
#export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
WorkingDirectory=/tmp/myworkdir
ExecStart=/path/to/myscript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With some configurations, the service starts but the status command says that it is dead (while it is actually running). With others it does not start. With none it stops with the command stop ....

I tried `Type=Simple`, forking, oneshot... always some problem.

I would simply that after boot or when user launch systemctl start myservice, service start, and if after some time crash will be started again. And if I will run systemclt stop myservice it stops and not need to kill the process.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly it need to be said, that concept "service" greatly differs in Linux/Unix and Windows environment. From your question seems to me you are looking for Unix solution.

In unix you typically register some statup and stop script/command. The startup script just runs your java application via java -jar app.jar. This application does business logic & also opens listening on some SHUTDOWN port.

The stop script/command just invokes another (or the same with different cmd parameters) java application which does nothing else just sending STOP command to original application's SHUTDOWN port.

You can look in more detail for example on tomcat startup/stop scripts - they are doing exactly this.

For windows is better to use some wrappers like WinRun4J or whatever else. Of course you can have one multiplatform maven archetype for "universal multiplatform" service like we do.

EDITED:
If you are still unsure how to configure it on Linux, read https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-systemd-service-unit-in-linux

ExecStart will be the startup java -jar app.jar and ExecStop will be the stopping command java -jar app-stopper.jar

Comment: Hi, i can stop the daemon with a rest call by wget or curl. So you suggest me to clone the tomcat skeleton of service?

Comment: Not exactly clone but be inspired.